# Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:home_widget/home_widget_callback_dispatcher.dart' not found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-packages

A very strange issue. I am using https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget and I am trying to use the backgroundCallback to refresh my widget by pressing an image on the widget. It works fine on debug mode, however when I build apk or run flutter run --release --verbose I get the error below (well in apk I can't see the error but it does not work either).

I get this error after tapping the image with the callback URI:

```
[+7444 ms] E/flutter ( 9412): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library
'package:home_widget/home_widget_callback_dispatcher.dart' not found.
[   +2 ms] E/flutter ( 9412): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(668)] Could not resolve main entrypoint function.
[        ] E/flutter ( 9412): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(167)] Could not run the run main Dart entrypoint.
[        ] E/flutter ( 9412): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(385)] Could not create root isolate.
[        ] E/flutter ( 9412): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(604)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

That makes no sense to me. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzTKW.jpg) that the file is in my package beside the other one. Does anyone know why this might happen?

What confuses me is that it is working fine in Debug.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.4.0-19.0.pre.35, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.856], locale en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✗] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.67.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with AndroidAlarmManager. Seems like since the last flutter update, running the app with the **--release flag won't let service extensions run** [(see the docs here)](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes). This is new, it used to work in the release mode. You can **use the --profile mode**, which strips down some of the debugging functionality, so the app runs smoothly (unlike in the debug mode), but still lets service extensions run.

Again, it is well explained in [the docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes), if you want to go into detail.

#### Solution:

```
flutter run --profile
```

Hope this fixes your problem.

Regards,
Honza

Answer (score 0):

add this code --> @pragma('vm:entry-point')

STEP 1 : Project -> External Libraies -> Dart Packages -> home_widget-0.1.6 -> home_widget_callback_dispatcher.dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWcLl.png)

STEP 2 :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH0SQ.png)

see also Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:background_fetch/background_fetch.dart' not found

Home Widget -> flutter run --release it is work I leave the application link below, you can test it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramzey.bankadovizpro

Source Code : https://www.roketnot.com/not/1608-home-screen-widget-kullanimi-telefonun-ana-ekranina-widget-koyma

same problem here
[Flutter Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:home_widget/home_widget_callback_dispatcher.dart' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74675682/flutter-dart-error-dart-lookuplibrary-library-packagehome-widget-home-widget/74923454#74923454)

Comment: Add code instead of adding images